# Parsing enumerations with CFG

Tags: python, context-free-grammar, pyparsing

I have a string that was generated from a rich text enumeration, for example:

> "(1) Let X denote one of the following: (a) weight (b) height (c)
>   depth (2) Y denote (a) color, except (i) white (ii) blue (b) pressure"

I want to construct the original structure, for example:

```
{"Let X denote one of the following:" : {"weight":{}, "height":{}, "depth":{}} , 
"Y denote": {"color, except": {"white":{}, "blue":{}}}, "pressure":{} }
```

It is very apparent that this is context-free-grammar, however I had trouble implementing it `pyparsing`

### Edit

I am no expert in CFG, so I hope this BNF representations is correct:

Assuming the following:

1. `w` is the equivalent of any character (`re.compile("\w*")`)
2. `l` is equivalent to `re.compile("[a-z]")`
3. `d` is equivalent to `re.compile("\d+")
4. `r` is equivalent to roman numerals (`i`,`ii`,`iii` ,...)

Then (hopefully), the BNF should look something like this

```
<E1>::= "(" <d> ")" | <E1> " "
<E2>::= "(" <l> ")" | <E2> " "
<E3>::= "(" <r> ")" | <E3> " "
<L0>::= <w> | <w> <E1> <L1> <L0>
<L1>::= <w> | <w> <E2> <L2> <L1>
<L2>::= <w> | <w> <E3> <L2>
```

Comment: Before you start implementing anything, whether in pyparsing, PLY, or any other parsing library, write a BNF for your expression. Then write a succession of test strings going from simple to complex. (It may be simpler to start with the test strings, and then do the BNF based on what you learned from writing them.) Test your BNF against them, and tweak it as necessary. *Then* start implementing the BNF in pyparsing or whatever. Edit your question to include the BNF, and where you are struggling with the pyparsing implementation.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcG, I've edited the question to my best understanding of `BNF`, please let me know if that is doable with pyparsing

Comment: What expression is supposed to match your overall expression? None of the `Ln` starts with `E1`, which is what your test string starts with. Also, leave out the spaces, pyparsing skips whitespace by default, so just focus on the printable stuff. Your test string also includes a colon and a comma, neither of which are included in your BNF. Lastly, please list out a series of sample test strings, going from simple to complex, and hand test them against your BNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first part of your parser using pyparsing expressions:

```
import pyparsing as pp

LPAR, RPAR = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
COMMA, COLON = map(pp.Literal, ",:")
wd = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
letter = pp.oneOf(list(pp.alphas.lower())) 
integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer
roman = pp.Word('ivx')

e1 = LPAR + integer + RPAR
e2 = LPAR + letter + RPAR
e3 = LPAR + roman + RPAR
```

The next part, based on your BNF, might look like:

```
# predefine levels using Forwards, since they are recursive
lev0 = pp.Forward()
lev1 = pp.Forward()
lev2 = pp.Forward()

lev0 <<= wd | wd + e1 + lev1 + lev0
lev1 <<= wd | wd + e2 + lev2 + lev1
lev2 <<= wd | wd + e3 + lev2
```

I assume that `lev0` is supposed to parse your test string being the 0'th level of nesting.

As I mentioned in the comments to your question, this fails immediately since your test string starts with "(1)" but your levels don't start with any of the `e` expressions.

Before continuing, your BNF implements repetition in a classic BNF form:

```
e ::= some expression
list_of_e ::= e (list_of_e | empty)
```

In pyparsing, you would implement this a little more directly:

```
wd = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
list_of_wd = pp.OneOrMore(wd)
# or using tuple multiplication short-hand
list_of_wd = wd * (1,)
```

Looking at your example, I rewrote the levels of your BNF as:

```
wds = pp.Group(wd*(1,))
lev0 <<= e1 + wds + lev1*(0,)
lev1 <<= e2 + wds + lev2*(0,)
lev2 <<= e3 + wds
expr = lev0()*(1,)
expr.ignore(COMMA | COLON)
```

(I didn't see the commas or colons helping in the parsing, so I just ignore them.)

Using `expr` to parse your string:

```
tests = """\
(1) Y denote (a) color (b) pressure
(1) Let X denote one of the following: (a) weight (b) height (c) depth (2) Y denote (a) color, except (i) white (ii) blue (b) pressure
"""

for test in tests.splitlines():
    print(test)
    expr.parseString(test).pprint()
    print()
```

We get:

```
(1) Y denote (a) color (b) pressure
[1, ['Y', 'denote'], 'a', ['color'], 'b', ['pressure']]

(1) Let X denote one of the following: (a) weight (b) height (c) depth (2) Y denote (a) color, except (i) white (ii) blue (b) pressure
[1,
 ['Let', 'X', 'denote', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'following'],
 'a',
 ['weight'],
 'b',
 ['height'],
 'c',
 ['depth'],
 2,
 ['Y', 'denote'],
 'a',
 ['color', 'except'],
 'i',
 ['white'],
 'ii',
 ['blue'],
 'b',
 ['pressure']]
```

So it parsed, in the sense that it got through the whole input string, but all we've done is basic tokenizing, and have not represented any of the structure implied by your integer/alpha/roman nested lists.

Pyparsing includes a grouping class to structure the results:

```
G = pp.Group
wds = G(wd*(1,))
lev0 <<= G(e1 + G(wds + lev1*(0,)))
lev1 <<= G(e2 + G(wds + lev2*(0,)))
lev2 <<= G(e3 + wds)
expr = lev0()*(1,)
expr.ignore(COMMA | COLON)
```

This gives output that better preserves your hierarchical structure:

```
(1) Y denote (a) color (b) pressure
[[1, [['Y', 'denote'], ['a', [['color']]], ['b', [['pressure']]]]]]

(1) Let X denote one of the following: (a) weight (b) height (c) depth (2) Y denote (a) color, except (i) white (ii) blue (b) pressure
[[1,
  [['Let', 'X', 'denote', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'following'],
   ['a', [['weight']]],
   ['b', [['height']]],
   ['c', [['depth']]]]],
 [2,
  [['Y', 'denote'],
   ['a', [['color', 'except'], ['i', ['white']], ['ii', ['blue']]]],
   ['b', [['pressure']]]]]]
```

A full parser would actually comprehend the concepts of "one of the following" vs. "all of the following", and inclusion and exclusion of elements, but that is beyond the scope of this question.